# hidden variable not emitting value attribute on Empty value

Tags: html, asp.net, hidden-variables

I have below line in my aspx page -

```
 <input type="hidden" id="test" name="test" value="" runat="server"/>
```

now when I run this aspx page, it does not emit the "value" attribute as empty.
below is snipet from page source of rendered aspx page -

```
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolder$test" type="hidden" id="ctl00_PlaceHolder_test"/>
```

It should have been -

```
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolder$test" type="hidden" id="ctl00_PlaceHolder_test" value=""/>
```

Please help in identifying why `value=""` is not appearing in page source.

Comment: Why is it important to transport unused elements?

Comment: Its used for page tracking(Analytics) purpose, the tracker is checking for value element.